# XPath: filter after part of attribute-name and attribute-value

Tags: xml, xpath

Happy new year!!

I'd like to find any node

- everywere in the doc
- with a specific name (e.g. val)
- that has attributes start with a specific string (e.g. p) and
- these attribute-value matches a specific rule (e.g. > 5)

I tried

```
//val/@*[starts-with (name(),'p')]
```

which does it all without the last requirement (attr-value).

I think of something like

```
//val/@*[starts-with (name(),'p') and val()>5]
```

but I do not know a function to access the attribute-value.

any help? thanks!!

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for dot (`.`), which is a reference to current context node :

```
//val/@*[starts-with(name(),'p') and .>5]
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/58s73vefZ)</kbd>**

**input XML :**

```
<root>
    <val>foo</val>
    <val p="9">bar</val>
    <val p="4">baz</val>
</root>
```

**output :**

```
p="9"
```